# Non-diagonalizable 2x2 matrix norm strictly greater than spectral radius

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-norms, spectral-radius

I've seen many answers to problems similar to this, yet I couldn't solve it.

Let $J= \mathbb{C}^{2x2}$ be the matrix:
$$J = \begin{pmatrix}\lambda & 1\\ 0 & \lambda\end{pmatrix}$$

Show that for every norm of $\mathbb{C}^2$, $||J|| = \max_\limits{||x|| = 1} ||J\,x|| > |\lambda|$.

I also have the following hint.

**Hint**: Calculate $||J^k\, x||$, where $x = (1\ \lambda)^T$.

Proving $||J|| \geq |\lambda|$ is easy, and I was able to show that $||J^k\, x|| = |\lambda|^k ||k\ v + x||$, where $v = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ is the eigenvector associated with $\lambda$. I'm also aware that $v$ can be freely chosen so that $||v|| = 1$.

However, I haven't been able to prove that it is **strictly** greater than $\lambda$.

Comment: We have $\|A\|^n\ge\|A^n\|\ge\left\|A^n\pmatrix{0\\ 1}\right\|=\left\|\pmatrix{n\lambda^{n-1}\\ \lambda^n}\right\|$. When $\lambda\ne0$, use the triangle inequality to prove that the last term is greater than $|\lambda|^n$ when $n$ is large.

Comment: @user1551 Even though the question got already answered, I'm still thinking about this way to solve it. I realize my previous answer to your comment made no real sense (therefore, I deleted it), however, I still don't get how you would use the triangle inequality here, since there is no sum? I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here, sorry for that

Comment: It's the same as how Ullrich does it in his answer: by triangle inequality, $$
\left\|\pmatrix{n\lambda^{n-1}\\ \lambda^n}\right\|
\ge\left\|\pmatrix{n\lambda^{n-1}\\ 0}\right\|
-\left\|\pmatrix{0\\ -\lambda^n}\right\|.
$$ and the RHS is greater than zero when $n>|\lambda|\left\|\pmatrix{1\\ 0}\right\|^{-1}\left\|\pmatrix{0\\ 1}\right\|$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I should have noticed, but it seems I'm still not completely awake. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proof that doesn't require us to know anything about the underlying norm on $\Bbb C^2$:

Wlog $\lambda\ne0$. Let $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1/\lambda\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$We need to show that $$||A||>1.$$

> > **Lemma.** Suppose $E$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix, $E\ne0$ and $E^2=0$. Then $||I+E||>1$.

Proof: $(I+E)^n=I+nE$ for $n=1,2,\dots$, so $$||I+E||^n\ge||(I+E)^n||\ge n||E||-||I||\to\infty.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm having some trouble showing $||(I+E)^n|| \geq n||E||−||I||$, even though it seems obvious.
I mean, I get that $||(I+E)^n|| = ||I + nE||$, and it should be trivial that the inequality you wrote is true, but I somehow don't get it...

Comment: "reverse triangle inequality:" $||a+b||\ge||a||-||b||.$ (Proof: $||a||=||(a+b)-b||\le||a+b||+||b||$.)

Comment: Thanks, that answers everything. Already accepted your answer